# Find the instantaneous rate of change at $ x=1$

Tags: calculus, rate-of-convergence

As I have said on my previous question ,I have a quiz tomorrow! And I need to get ready , but this question in my quiz review has been a problem for me! So basically it asks the instantaneous rate of change when $x=1$.
[image]

4A Is preety easy on the above questions , but 4B Has been hunting me!

> **Find the instantaneous rate of change at x=1.**

4C , and 4D Are the same types of question as they both ask the slope of the line , so all you have to do is find the points from (2,2.5) (for 4C) , then you get the slope using $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$

Answer from teacher I couldn't understand:

[image]

Comment: What is the instantaneous rate of change at a maximum/minimum?

Comment: @mfl she didnt give us that.. And let me post the answer she gave us.. 2 sec

Comment: What do you mean by "2 sec"? The answer is $0$ feet/second.

Comment: @mfl i meant wait 2 seconds until i post answer i didnt understand.. I will post answer and i just did post the answer

Comment: Oh, sorry. I have thought that 2 sec was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

At $x=1$, draw a tanget line. The slope of that tanget line will give you the instantaneous rate of change at $x=1$. The tanget line has slope $m=0$.

Comment: How do you get the slope of the tangent line?

Comment: The tanget line looks like this ---------------------. It's a horizontal line. All horizontal lines have slope, $m=0$.

Comment: Aaorn so you are implying all of these types of questions are 0.. like instantaneous rate of change.. because in your words , "All horizontal lines have slope, m=0"

Comment: They do, and in this case, because the tanget line is horizontal, then the slope, $m=0$.

Comment: The dude above is saying its not when they are not horizontal like C And D.. Well i replied with "Ok so tell me this please , because i need to get ready for quiz!!! For C For example , we find the point at 2 and 2.5 , and then find their slope? And for D Same thing you find point 3 and 3.5 (all increasing by 0,5) , and then find their slope?" .. Can you answer that?

Comment: @amanuel2 you really have to understand the concepts. Tanget lines to the points C and D are non-horizontal, as mentioned in the above answer. A tanget line is basically, the slope at an instant.

Comment: Ok so tell me this please , because i need to get ready for quiz!!! For C For example , we find the point at 2 and 2.5 , and then find their slope? And for D Same thing you find point 3 and 3.5 (all increasing by 0,5) , and then find their slope?

Answer (score 1):

Before 1 second the rate of change is positive because the line is going up.
After 1 second the rate of change is negative because the line is going down.

At 1 second the line is flat so it must be zero.

Comment: Are all of these types of problems $m=0$ , since the slope of a tangent is 0?

Comment: If the tangent is horizontal then the rate of change is 0.  However at the other points it has a nonzero value because the tangent isn't horizontal.

Comment: Oh Wait! So C And D Are those types of question where it is non-horizontal which you were talking about right?

Comment: Yes C and D are non horizontal.

Comment: Ok so tell me this please , because i need to get ready for quiz!!! For C For example , we find the point at 2 and 2.5 , and then find their slope? And for D Same thing you find point 3 and 3.5 (all increasing by 0,5) , and then find their slope?

Comment: The way your teacher is solving this is to draw a line parallel to the tangent (parallel lines have the same slopes).  Then working out the slope by $ \frac{rise}{run} $

Comment: Where rise is the amount of movement up between the two points (negative values to represent movement down) and run is the amount of movement from left to right.

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying . What? can you be more clear to a not so smart student?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46717/discussion-between-amanuel2-and-q-the-platypus).